# Is Varnish compatible with Django Csrf protection?

Tags: django, varnish

I would like to put Varnish as a in front of a corporate website built with Django, to improve its performance. On every single page of the site there is a small contact us form. Other than that, the site is mostly static. The trouble is I can't figure out how to combine Varnish with Djangos Csrf protection. I suppose the same question applies to any sort of full-page caching with the Django csrf protection.

I suppose turning off the csrf middleware is a no-no - right?

matti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I would suggest you to start using [Django + Varnish ESI](http://yml-blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/esi-using-varnish-and-django.html).

In case if you use only full page caching - I suggest you the following workaround:

1. Move forms loading to AJAX call (to POST request)
2. In your `vcl` file either mark only GET requests for `lookup` or mark POST requests for `hit_for_pass`.

Comment: You're right, those are the only viable options. I think the Ajax Post solution is probably easiest to implement. The form could be loaded and rendered in a regular GET request without the csrf token and only when the user decides to submit the form a request is made to the server (through Ajax to receive the token which is then used to submit the form).